# Jquery AJAX shows webpage when form is submitted successfully

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form in PHP am sending via AJAX Jquery. The form is sent successfully via AJAX JQuery but the webpage is shown when the success message shows or the form is sent. What might be the exact problem causing this.

```
<? php include_once 'config.php'; if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) { $staff_number=$ _POST[ 'staff_number']; $department=$ _POST[ 'department']; $stmt=$ link->prepare("INSERT INTO `staffs` (`staff_name`,`department`) VALUES (?,?)"); $stmt->bind_param('ss',$staff_name, $staff_number, $designation, $department); if ($stmt->execute()){ echo "<span style='background-color:#69d052; 

padding:6px; 
            color:white; font-size:13px;border-radius:5px;'>Staff created 
               successfully. </span>"; } else{ echo "
<p align=center>Error inserting data.</p>"; echo mysqli_error($link); } } ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-3">
            <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="my_form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Staff Name</label>
                    <input type="text" required="true" name="staff_name" class="form-control" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Department</label>
                    <input input="text" name="department" class="form-control" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="message_box" style="margin:50px 0px;">
                </div>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/   libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.message_box').html('Processing...');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        data: $('form').serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('.message_box').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                            $("#my_form")[0].reset();
                        }
                    });

                });

            });
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You say, that "The form is sent successfully", but the question is: where? The url is never specified. Your ajax request should have a destination "url". (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: what if the destination url is the same page

Answer (score 1):

You might be **Redirecting** the request after success from the server side (PHP). That's why a page is showing.

Answer (score 0):

In you ajax call you are not setting your url property, by default this will be set to the current page, that is why you might be getting the page instead.

try adding your url, to your ajax...

```
$.ajax({
     url: '..my ajax url.....', 
     type: 'post',
     data: $('form').serialize(),
     success: function(data) {
      $('.message_box').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
      $("#my_form")[0].reset();
     }
    });
```

Comment: the url is on the same page and I added but is the same issue